# How to fill area between two line charts in TeeChart HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

I would like to fill the area between two line charts when the area is enclosed between the lines. See below. (TeeChart was not used to draw these charts)

How can I accomplish this in TeeChart HTML5 component?

**Chart now:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeriesRegion tool is a tool designed for this purpose, and it's implemented in the majority of TeeChart versions, but I'm afraid it isn't in TeeChart HTML5/JavaScript yet. I've added it to the wish list to be implemented in future releases (TF77016627).